abnormal import error behaviour in python
I am trying to run a python script that contains the following line.
from __future__ import annotations

import math
from typing import Any, Optional, Union

import geometry as gm
import tk
import matplotlib
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors as mcolors
import numpy as np
from numpy.random import uniform as unif  # pylint: disable=g-importing-member


matplotlib.use('TkAgg')


I get the following error-
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/janamzaveri/KRR/alphageometry/numericals.py", line 30, in <module>
    matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
  File "/Users/janamzaveri/KRR/alphageometry/krr_proj/lib/python3.10/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 1255, in use
    plt.switch_backend(name)
  File "/Users/janamzaveri/KRR/alphageometry/krr_proj/lib/python3.10/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 415, in switch_backend
    module = backend_registry.load_backend_module(newbackend)
  File "/Users/janamzaveri/KRR/alphageometry/krr_proj/lib/python3.10/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/registry.py", line 323, in load_backend_module
    return importlib.import_module(module_name)
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.14_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Users/janamzaveri/KRR/alphageometry/krr_proj/lib/python3.10/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_tkagg.py", line 1, in <module>
    from . import _backend_tk
  File "/Users/janamzaveri/KRR/alphageometry/krr_proj/lib/python3.10/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/_backend_tk.py", line 9, in <module>
    import tkinter as tk
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.14_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/tkinter/__init__.py", line 37, in <module>
    import _tkinter # If this fails your Python may not be configured for Tk
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_tkinter'

However if I run this code on the python interpreter, I cannot reproduce this error and it runs without any issues. why is this happening?
Python 3.10.14 (main, Mar 19 2024, 21:46:16) [Clang 15.0.0 (clang-1500.3.9.4)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import matplotlib
>>> matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
>>>


You tagged the question with [virtual-environment]. Is a venv in play and how?

I am running my python shell and script with the venv activated.

Could you add this debug statement: import sys; print(sys.prefix) and post what does it print? It should be the same value (the venv directory) in both cases.
